# Nlog Trace not writing to Azure logs

Tags: asp.net, azure, trace, nlog, azure-cloud-services

I have a web application that I have deployed into Azure.  I am using NLog to do error logging and have been struggling to get the Trace and logging functionality to work in Azure.

Here's the problem:
I have file logging and email alerting enabled, which works fine in my locally deployed IIS instance.  I have enabled Trace logging too in the NLog config and that works too (I can see the Trace messages firing in the Output window in visual studio while the website processes requests locally).  If I write an explicit Diagnostics.Trace call, it will also appear in the Output window.

The problem occurs when I deploy my code up to Azure and call my methods.  I have turned on Application logging in the Diagnostics section and also checked in the Log Stream but the Nlog trace statements don't get picked up (but the direct Trace statements do work!)... It also appears that the file logging doesn't work in Azure too (though that could be folder permissions).  I'm wondering if it's my config transforms or something else?!

This is driving me crazy, I can't work out what is wrong.

NLog Config (in Web.Config):

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="Trace" name="ETWTrace" layout="[${longdate:universalTime=true} ${processid}:${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message} Exception: ${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/Logs/Api-${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" layout="[${longdate:universalTime=true} ${processid}:${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message} Exception: ${exception:format=tostring}" encoding="UTF-8" />
      <target name="Mail" xsi:type="Mail" html="true" subject="[xDebug] Fatal Error" body="[${longdate:universalTime=true} ${processid}:${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message}" to="x@x.com" from="x@x.com" encoding="UTF-8" smtpUserName="xxxxx" enableSsl="True" smtpPassword="xxxxx" smtpAuthentication="Basic" smtpServer="smtp.sendgrid.net" smtpPort="587" />
   </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile,ETWTrace" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="Mail" />
  </rules>
```

Web.Release.Config:

```
    <nlog xdt:Transform="Replace"
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">

    <targets>
      <target xsi:type="Trace" name="ETWTrace" layout="[${longdate:universalTime=true} ${processid}:${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message} Exception: ${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/App_Data/Logs/Api-${date:universalTime=true:format=yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" layout="[${longdate:universalTime=true} ${processid}:${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message} Exception: ${exception:format=tostring}" encoding="UTF-8" />
      <target name="Mail" smtpDeliveryMethod="network" xsi:type="Mail" html="true" subject="[xDev] Fatal Error" body="[${longdate:universalTime=true} ${processid}:${threadid}] ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message}" to="x@xx.com" from="xx@xx.com" Encoding="UTF-8" smtpUsername="xxxx" enableSsl="True" smtpPassword="xxx" smtpAuthentication="Basic" smtpServer="smtp.sendgrid.net" smtpPort="587" />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile,ETWTrace" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Fatal" writeTo="Mail" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

I thought maybe something was wrong with my config transform but I've downloaded the web.config from the server and it looks fine so maybe it's something else underlying which is causing the nlog calls to fail?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? It looks like we are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I've recently struggled with NLog not writing any logs when deployed to Azure.  I _solved_ the problem by removing all name pattern filtering in my rule definitions.  It doesn't look like you have that in your config, but it was the only way I could get it working on azure.  This solution feels wrong, but after losing a full day to the problem I had to move on.